# Mysql incorrect data getting with like query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the data from `user_id = 1` in this query, but there are different `user_id` values in the incoming data.

```
select * 
from user_contacts uc 
inner join contacts_email_addresses ce on uc.id=ce.contact_id 
inner join contacts_phone_numbers cp on uc.id=cp.contact_id 
where uc.user_id=1 
   and cp.user_id=1 
   and ce.user_id=1 
   and uc.contact_name like '%test%' 
   or uc.contact_surname like '%test%' 
   or ce.email_address like '%test%' 
   or cp.phone_number like '%test%'
```

Comment: you should probably put all the OR clause wrapped in parenthesys to ensure the precedence in evaluating. `and (uc.contact_name like '%test%' 
   or uc.contact_surname like '%test%' 
   or ce.email_address like '%test%' 
   or cp.phone_number like '%test%')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All these AND conditions are only being applied with the first "or" condition (uc.contact_name like '%test%').
Use a parenthesis like this:

```
select * 
from user_contacts uc 
inner join contacts_email_addresses ce 
  on uc.id=ce.contact_id 
inner join contacts_phone_numbers cp 
  on uc.id=cp.contact_id 
where uc.user_id=1 and 
      cp.user_id=1 and 
      ce.user_id=1 and 
     (uc.contact_name like '%test%' or 
      uc.contact_surname like '%test%' or 
      ce.email_address like '%test%' or 
      cp.phone_number like '%test%')
```

Comment: @NiyaziAlpay : welcome to stack overflow. If you find this answers your question, please mark it as the "accepted answer". That's the best way to say thank you here.